# Alternative definition of product measure.

Tags: measure-theory

While reading some notes the concept of product measures showed up and it was defined by $\int \phi(x,y)d\mu\otimes\nu(x,y)=\int\phi(x,y)d\mu(x)d\nu(y)$ (I think there should have some conditions on $\phi$ here). I was surprised because I thought that to define a measure one need to define how it acts on measurable set (I thought that the product measure was the only one such that $\mu\otimes\nu(A\times B)= \mu(A)\nu(B)$ for all $A$ $\mu$-measurable and $B$ $\nu$-measurable). But is this the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation holds for all non-negative measuarble functions $\phi$ iff the second equation holds for all measurable sets $A$ and $B$.

If the first one holds just take $\phi (x,y)=1$ for $x \in A, y \in B$ and $0$ for all other $(x,y)$ to get the second equation.

Suppose the second equation holds. Consider the collection of all measuarble sets $E$ in the product for which the first equation holds with $\phi (x,y)=1$ for $(x,y) \in E$ and $0$ for all other $(x,y)$. This is a sigma algebra which contains all measurable rectangles $A \times B$. Hence, it contains all measurable sets $E$ in the product. Now use a straightforward simple function approximation to finish the proof.